# How to run keepass portable on mac and windows

Tags: windows, macos, password-management, password-protection, keepass

I am using keepass portable (have it on a usb). I want to be able to use it for mac and windows. I tried following the steps on keepass' website (install mono on the usb and run it and the keepass app on top of mono with a batch file) but this lacked one thing....It didn't help me with the fact the keepass app was an exe so it would't open on OS X. So I attempted to use keepassx when on OS X and keepass when on windows. This almost worked, BUT the latest version of keepassx doesn't support the .kdbx file (which is what the latest Keepass uses). How can I achieve seamlessly running Keepass on OS X or Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So  finally, here is what I did to be able to run keepass portable on mac and windows seamlessly:

1. Download Keepass portable "classic edition"
2. Place the contents of the unzipped package on your USB
3. Download KeepassX and put the application from the dmg on your USB
4. Run either the KeepassX (if on OS X) or KeePass.exe (if on Windows obviously)

And thats how you do it! KeepassX and Keepass.exe both use .kdb for the database so everything works perfect! Only difference is on OS X you use the Keepass application, and on Windows you use the Keepass.exe

Comment: KeePassX version 2.x now supports KeePass2 files. Alternatively KeeWeb can be used on macOS